# Django test client get row id from query

Tags: django, django-tests

How can i print the id from the response in the below code.The user does exist in the DB.Also i come across this error.

```
from django.test import Client

c = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=False)
response = c.post('/reg/_user/', {'firstname': 'test', 'lastname' : '_test'})
```

views get_user

```
def _user(request):
  try:
    response_dict = {}
    qd = request.POST
    firstname = qd.__getitem__('firstname')
    lastname = qd.__getitem__('lastname')
    up = UserProfile.objects.get(first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname)
    print up.id
    return up.id
  except:
    pass
```

Error:

```
 response = c.post('/reg/_user/', {'firstname': 'test', 'lastname' : '_test'})
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 483, in post
 response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 302, in post
 return self.request(**r)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 444, in request
 six.reraise(*exc_info)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 201, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request, response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 30, in process_response
if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your tests, but with the view itself. In Django a view always has to return a [HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects). Sometimes this is achieved using a shortcut function like [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), but it in turn also returns an HttpResponse object.

If for some reason you just want to return an otherwise empty page with this single value you could change

```
return up.id
```

to

```
return HttpResponse(up.id)
```

Also, I wonder: Did you create the view just to test `UserProfile` and don't use it as a view on the actual site? If so, this code doesn't belong in a view, it should be put into the unittest itself. You should only use the test client to test actual, real views.

---

On an mostly unrelated, but quite important note. This:

```
try:
    # your view code
except:
    pass
```

is a strong **antipattern**. Why would you want to silence all the potential problems? You should really stop doing that.

Comment: and a minor thing: `qd.__getitem__('firstname')` is synonymous with `qd['firstname']`, but the former is much shorter and clearer :)

Comment: There's also `qd.get('firstname')`, which will not throw an exception if the item doesn't exist (it will return `None` instead).

Comment: I don't understand your question, unfortunately. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I want to get the id in a variable in my test file.How can i do  it

Comment: Using `response.content`, but do you use the view outside of tests? If not move the view code to the test itself, it doesn't look like what you need is a view.